# VSTest unit test results are not showing in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have an issue getting SonarQube to pickup the unittest results.

The setup is as following:

- TFS2015 Update 3
- New SonarQube Build Tasks (released a few days ago)
- SonarQube 6.2
- C# Plugin 5.5.1.522

From the verboose log it appears that the trx files are identified, but I can't find anything about those beeing processed, even with verbose logging.

2016-12-16T13:26:54.5935752Z 14:26:54.516  Looking for TRX files in: E:\TFS_Build\Agent01\Work\49\TestResults

2016-12-16T13:26:54.5945826Z 14:26:54.518  Located a test results file: E:\TFS_Build\Agent01\Work\49\TestResults\tap_sysadmin_TFS-BUILD1 2016-12-16 14_26_32.trx

The trx file does contain test results.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: I tried with a fixed .trx filename and adding parameter /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths to point to the trx file - but still 0 unit tests are shown. I also tried with codecoverage disabled. No matter what, the codecoverage is reported fine but no unittest results are available.